# uniq command not detected duplicated lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, uniq

I'm facing a difficulty with the unix `uniq` command. 
I have a file containing a list of ids that looks like this (output from `head -5 list.txt`) :

```
IBNUKWG02JZU4E
IBNUKWG02JZULO
IBNUKWG02JZUMG
IBNUKWG02JZUZS
IBNUKWG02JZV0R
```

The files contains **619142** lines (`cat list.txt | wc -l` ), and contains duplicate, for example if I run the command ( `-c` flag returns the number of occurrence of the line )

```
cat list.txt | grep IBNUKWG02JZULO | uniq -c
```

it returns

```
  2 IBNUKWG02JZULO
```

but if I run the command ( `-u` flag to only print unique lines)

```
   cat list.txt | uniq -u | wc -l
```

it returns **619142**, as if duplicated lines weren't detected. How is it possible ?

Comment: The lines need to be sorted, uniq only checks adjacent lines.

Comment: ok thanks I lot, looks liek I didn't pay enough attention to the `uniq` documentation

Answer (score 6):

before using uniq use sort.

```
cat list.txt | sort | uniq -u | wc -l
```

Comment: The useless use of `cat` can be avoided here, just `sort list.txt | uniq -c` would be good

Comment: yep, i know, just copied from his question. :)))